# How can I remove bar below the project hierarchy bar?

Tags: java, android

I want to remove the shortcut bar which shows the method signatures and class name in a bar below the project hierarchy in a `Java` file and also in `xml` files it shows the layout hierarchy as in the picture on selecting any of the picture it get us to the defination of particular method or layout.

[image: XML file]

[image: Java file]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Mac OSX

Change

Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> [x] Show breadcrumbs

to

Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> [ ] Show breadcrumbs

Comment: But the answer you gave is for android studio in Mac in ubuntu and windows it is located some where else. I managed to get this thing working by searching "breadcrums" in settings and turned it off.